# jQuery 3.6.0 onload seems to be not working

Tags: jquery

I have used **jQuery** v3.6.0.
It seems to not working.

I want to fade out the class(alert) after a few seconds when the class (alert) loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".alert").on("load", function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".alert").fadeOut();
            }, 3000);
        });
    });
```

I have used the following code, but it seems to be not working.
Is there any problem in my code.
Please Help Me To Sort It Out

Comment: What do you think you mean by "*when the class (alert) loads*" - do you have some other code that adds a new element to the DOM?  Are you adding that class?  Is it an image?   Does it do what you want if you just remove `$(".alert").on("load", function() {`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

There is no need to have a `load()` for this class (`.alert`).
This is because your `setTimeout()` function will only run once the DOM is loaded because you are using the `$(document).ready()` method. Everything inside the `$(document).ready()` will only run once the DOM has loaded (including the .alert class).

You can remove the additional load function completely and this will work :)

But please be reminded of this in the docs for `$(document).ready()`:

> - $( handler )
> - $( document ).ready( handler )
> - $( "document" ).ready(    handler )
> - $( "img" ).ready( handler )
> - $().ready( handler )
>
> As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other
> syntaxes still work but are deprecated. This is because the selection
> has no bearing on the behavior of the .ready() method, which is
> inefficient and can lead to incorrect assumptions about the method's
> behavior. For example, the third syntax works with "document" which
> selects nothing. The fourth syntax waits for the document to be ready
> but implies (incorrectly) that it waits for images to become ready.

```js
console.log('DOM not loaded yet, so .alert is not ready');
// DOM is not ready yet here
$(document).ready(function() {
// DOM is ready, function will run
  console.log('DOM loaded, so .alert is visible - timeout will run');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeOut();
    console.log('.alert is now hidden');
  }, 3000);

});
```

```css
.alert {
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert">

</div>
```

Comment: According to the quote you've included, `$("alert").ready` does *nothing* as is the same as `$(() =>)` ie what we call doc.ready.

Comment: @freedomn-m you are absolutely correct! I'll update my answer.